# angularjs ng-if for defined but not valued objects

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that has a scope object named `asd` and,

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.asd = {
            "name": ""
    }
});
```

And I am using it in html code with `ng-if` like this.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
     <p ng-if="asd.name">
         Defined {{asd.name}}
     </p>
     <p ng-if="!asd.name">
         Non Defined
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code writes `Non Defined` but it defined. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rwty77nk/)

Does ng-if looks for object value? How can I use defined property of an object?

Comment: ng-if just works like JavaScript (ex: `if ($scope.asd.name)`). It tests if the expression is truthy or falsy. An empty string is falsy. Use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined

Answer (score 0):

Using angular.isDefined is a good suggestion. In that case, it is best to change your code by removing:

```
<p ng-if="asd.name">
   Defined {{asd.name}}
</p>
<p ng-if="!asd.name">
   Non Defined
</p>
```

And instead replacing it with a binding to a scope variable - then the checking for `asd.name` can be done inside your controller like this:

```
$scope.varStatus = "";
if(angular.isDefined($scope.asd.name)){
   $scope.varStatus = "Defined" $scope.asd.name;
}
else{
   $scope.varStatus = "Non Defined";
}
```

Then in your template, you do this (notice I only use scope variable `varStatus`):

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
     <p>
         {{varStatus}}
     </p>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Give it a try, I hope this helps.